# How to get a COUNT of NON-NULL members in a set with some conditions?

Tags: mdx, ssas-2012

To give you a slight background to the problem, there are certain "users" who do certain "tasks" which are categorized into various types; one such type being "DSR". The requirement I am faced with is to find ***how many requests of type DSR the userid 033343 worked on for each month of year 2013.***
What I would be needing is to get the count of the members in `set` of all the distinct requests a user (Userid = 033343) worked on in the year = 2013 and for the Request Type = DSR. 
Below is what I tried at first:

```
WITH SET requests AS
EXISTING [Request].[RequestID].MEMBERS

MEMBER Measures.[Count033343] AS
DISTINCTCOUNT(requests)

SELECT Measures.[Count033343] ON 1,
[Calendar].[CalendarMonthName].CHILDREN ON 0 /*Values like January, February, etc. Not tied to Calendar Years*/
FROM [Model]
WHERE(
                 [User].[UserID].&[033343],
                 [Request Type].[Request Type Name].&[DSR],
                 [Calendar].[CalendarYear].&[2013]

      )
```

But that didn't work. I got below result.

[image: Tuple in where clause]

I figured, there is an issue with the set that I was building.

Then I moving the MDX to the Set definition. I thought it might make the code work faster as compared to having an extra set of tuple in `WHERE` clause.

```
WITH SET requests AS
EXISTS([Request].[RequestID].MEMBERS, (
                     [User].[UserID].&[033343],
                     [Request Type].[Request Type Name].&[DSR],
                     [Calendar].[CalendarYear].&[2013]
      ))

MEMBER Measures.[Count033343] AS
DISTINCTCOUNT(requests)

SELECT Measures.[Count033343] ON 1,
[Calendar].[CalendarMonthName].MEMBERS ON 0
FROM [Model]
```

But I was still getting the same result as above - **0 as the count for all the months!**

Then, I thought of checking the set itself I was building(In the second example)

```
WITH SET requests AS
EXISTS([Request].[RequestId].MEMBERS, (
                     [User].[UserID].&[033343],
                     [Request Type].[Request Type Name].&[DSR],
                     [Calendar].[CalendarYear].&[2013]
      ))

SELECT [Measures].[Average of Late Tasks] ON 1,
requests ON 0
FROM [Model]
```

[image]

That proved two things.

1) The set was returning NULL values along with non null values.

2) There are indeed Request Ids returned from the set. So the count of Requests is definitely greater than 0 for the tuple specified.

I could use the `NON EMPTY` clause to remove the NON NULL values but, I don't want to use it as I read that it adds overhead.

As I have verified above that there are indeed **requests** for various **users** for all the **months** in 2013, why I am getting the count to be 0? Where am I going wrong? Why isn't the `EXISTS` and `EXISTING`functionality working as expected? Isn't the set supposed to return only those Request IDs which ***exist*** for the condition? Is my understanding wrong?

**EDIT**

For @whytheq - With your final query, I got non-zero values

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[x] AS
   Count(
     NONEMPTY(
       [Request].[RequestId].MEMBERS
       , {([Measures].[Average of Late Tasks])}
     )      
   )
SELECT 
   Measures.[x] ON 0,
   [Calendar].[CalendarYear].&[2013] ON 1 
FROM [Model]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
       x
2013   2
```

Comment: your 3rd script doesn't prove anything as the set you create `requests` isn't in the `SELECT` clause, or is this a typo `claims ON 0` ?

Comment: yup, a typo..corrected it

Comment: does the simplified third script in my "answer" (!) still return zeros?

Comment: Yup it still returns zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Not tested) Does this still return zeros?

```
WITH SET [requests] AS
  {([User].[UserID].&[033343],
  [Request Type].[Request Type Name].&[DSR])}
  * {[Measures].[Average of Late Tasks]}  //<<<<try running with and without this line
  * [Request].[RequestID].MEMBERS
MEMBER Measures.[Count033343] AS
  DISTINCTCOUNT(requests)
SELECT 
  [Calendar].[CalendarMonthName].CHILDREN ON 0,
  Measures.[Count033343] ON 1 
FROM [Model]
WHERE(
      [Calendar].[CalendarYear].&[2013]
      )
```

How about the following?

```
WITH 
  MEMBER Measures.[Count033343] AS
    DISTINCTCOUNT({[Request].[RequestID].[RequestID]})
SELECT 
  [Calendar].[CalendarMonthName].CHILDREN ON 0,
  Measures.[Count033343] ON 1 
FROM [Model]
WHERE(
      [Calendar].[CalendarYear].&[2013],
      [User].[UserID].&[033343],
      [Request Type].[Request Type Name].&[DSR]
      )
```

Maybe try this simpler query first and (if it works!) we can build up from this to try to locate the problem...

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[x] AS
   Count(
     NONEMPTY(
       [Request].[RequestId].MEMBERS
       , {([Measures].[Average of Late Tasks])}
     )      
   )
SELECT 
   Measures.[x] ON 0,
   [Calendar].[CalendarYear].&[2013] ON 1 
FROM [Model]
```

Comment: Yes, it is still zero.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti ok - I mocked up something similar in our cube and have added another script to my answer (although not confident it's going to work in yours!)

Comment: tried to take out a lot of the conditions in the third script to see is we can get a result and then maybe build it up

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti I'm not involved in cube design but wondering if there are settings for the hierarchy that need to be configured for `count` to function correctly?

Comment: My Apologies. The last query's result was non zero. I will edit the question with the query and

Comment: cool - if you run it with `WHERE [User].[UserID].&[033343]` on the end of the script what happens?

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti did my third script with `COUNT(NONEMPTY` answer the original question?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I would eventually mark yours as Answer. Right now I am having another question, which I edited back in the question. So keeping the question open for a little more time. Hope that's fine.

Comment: No problem - I used to do that as well - although I found to get a quicker response it is usually better to start another question p.s. do you have the Adventure Works cube? Might be good if you can replicate the behaviour against that cube and then create another question using the AdWks scripts. Just an idea.

Comment: Valid suggestion. I will post another question soon. And no, don't have Adventure Works cube. Whatever little R&D I do is on a copy of client's cube. Anyways if you can help on that next question, it would be awesome! TIA.

Comment: shame - our DBA installed AdWks cube onto our dev box - very useful - I would recommend as all `MSDN` articles use that cube.

Comment: another question added.