# Why DISTINCTCOUNT not giving the count of distinct members but COUNT(DISTINCT(NONEMPTY())) is working?

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2012

This is in continuation to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26506258/2993606) I posted on SO. So whats happening is `COUNT(NONEMPTY` seems to get me the count BUT `DISTINCTCOUNT` doesn't. The set(of values) on which I am running the functions are actually distinct. Here is the query I am using:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[x] AS
   Count(
     NONEMPTY(
       [Request].[RequestID].children
       , {([Measures].[Average of Late Tasks])}
     )      
   )

 MEMBER Measures.[y] AS
  DISTINCTCOUNT((
       [Request].[RequestID].children
       , {([Measures].[Average of Late Tasks])}
     ) )   

WITH MEMBER Measures.[z] AS
   Count(DISTINCT
     NONEMPTY(
       [Request].[RequestID].children
       , {([Measures].[Average of Late Tasks])}
     ))      
   ) 

SELECT 
   {Measures.[x], Measures.[y]} ON 0,
   [Calendar].[CalendarMonthName].children ON 1 
FROM [Model]
WHERE 
([Calendar].[CalendarYear].&[2014],
[User].[UserID].&[033343])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
           x    y   z
January    1    0   1
February   1    0   1
March      1    0   1
April      1    0   1
May        1    0   1
June       1    0   1
July       1    0   1
August     6    0   6
September  6    0   6
October    7    0   7
November   0    0   0
December   0    0   0
```

Question is, why does `COUNT(NONEMPTY(` work but DISTINCTCOUNT not? And that too when the RequestIDs are all distinct!

For instance, I checked the RequestIDs for month of August(Count = 6, see above result).

I ran the below MDX:

```
SELECT 
   [Measures].[Average of Late Tasks] ON 0,
   non empty ([Calendar].[CalendarMonthName].&[August], [Request].[RequestID].children) ON 1 
FROM [Model]
WHERE 
([Calendar].[CalendarYear].&[2014],
[User].[UserID].&[033343])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
                Average of Late Tasks
August  3157    0.00
August  3337    0.00
August  3769    0.00
August  4012    0.00
August  4191    0.00
August          1.22
```

Which means they are all distinct requests! And yet, `DISTINCTCOUNT` returns 0. What's going on around in the background here?!

Comment: +1 this is an interesting question - hopefully they'll be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`NonEmpty` is a function that has one or two arguments, which both should be sets, [according to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145988.aspx). On the other hand, `DistinctCount` is a function with just one argument, which should be a set, [according to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145519.aspx). Whatever your construct in parentheses

```
([Request].[RequestID].children
   , {([Measures].[Average of Late Tasks])}
)
```

is, it is not a well formed set definition. What you might want to use instead of

```
DISTINCTCOUNT((
   [Request].[RequestID].children
   , {([Measures].[Average of Late Tasks])}
 ) )
```

could be

```
DISTINCTCOUNT(Filter(
   [Request].[RequestID].children
   , Not(IsEmpty([Measures].[Average of Late Tasks]))
 ) )
```

[`IsEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145507.aspx) checks for NULL values in MDX. You cannot do that using `=`, as in numeric context, NULL is treated like 0 by `=`.

Anyway, I would assume this to be slower than the other two solutions.

Comment: It still gave zeroes.